# Modal loading twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem for load the content of modal from external url with ajax. All work fine, except that my modal is show twice, the first time the modal is empty and i see the loader gif of the ajax call. After, the modal re-load with good informations.

In my view, I have only one modal element :

```
<div id="TheModal" class="modal fade text-center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in a external javascript file, I do this for clear the previous data of the modal, and load new datas :

```
$(document).on('click', '.ls-modal', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-content').html('test');
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $('#TheModal').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Note that in the first load of my modal (which I want to delete), in the content I can see the word "test"...

Someone have an idea ?

Thank you, and sorry for my bad english !

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove individual handlers by using `.off()`

Try this code,

```
$(document).off('click', '.ls-modal');
$(document).on('click', '.ls-modal', function (e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-content').html('test');
    $('#TheModal .modal-content').html('');
    $('#TheModal').find('.modal-content').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

---

Reference:

- [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
- [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I had try, but it still does'nt wort. while the trus ajax call is loading, i see another modal with "test" content.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a custom javascript file that contains the actions to load the modal, make sure that you are only loading that javascript file once.

I had this issue when I was working with partial views in ASP.Net MVC.